# Issue with Datatables buttons displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, datatables

I have a wordpress site that is not showing the buttons for my datatables properly. In the past, I've had to have some help to reformat the traditional datatable code in order for it to display properly on this wordpress site, and I'm hoping that's what's happening here.

The page with the tables can be seen at testing.uwsinc.net/dashboardtest.

The other options seem to work fine but no buttons show up at all. However, If I try this on my testing site it shows up and functions perfectly. It could be a JS conflict but I'm getting out of my realm of expertise and I've been working on this for days and days with no luck. Any helpful tips are much appreciated, just any way for me to add a column show/hide option to this datatable.

```
<script type="text/javascript"   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/filtering/row-based/range_dates.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<label style="font-weight:bold;">Select the table you would like to view:
</label></br>
<select name='tables' id='select-tables'>
<option value="mytable">Survey Test Table</option>
<option value="mytableSurvey">Survey Only</option>
</select>
</br>


<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#mytable').DataTable({
dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [
    'copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'colvis'
]
});


$('#mytableSurvey').DataTable({
dom: 'Bfrtip',
buttons: [
    'copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'colvis'
]
});
$('.dataTable').wrap('<div class="dataTables_scroll" />');




$(document).on('change' , '#select-tables', function(){
var table = $(this).val();
$('#' + table +'_wrapper').show();
$('[id$="_wrapper"]').not('#' + table +'_wrapper').hide();
});
$("#select-tables").trigger("change");

});
}(jQuery));
</script>
```

How it should look:
[image]

How it does look:
[image]

Comment: _The page with the tables can be seen at ._ where?

Comment: The link didn't show sorry. Testing.uwsinc.net/dashboardtest

Comment: i can see dataTable.. not able to see your problem? can you please share a screen shot of testing site as well as production site?

Comment: Updated with images. You can see where the Column visibility button is not showing on the actual site i linked. This occurs in all browsers and devices.

Comment: it seems like the order of loading js is wrong.check order //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js
//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js
//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/pdfmake.min.js
//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/vfs_fonts.js
//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js
//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.print.min.js

Comment: @Dinesh I have tried with that order now as well and still no luck. If you check the site page, you can see there is still no colvis button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146434/discussion-between-dinesh-and-tom-n).

Comment: Sorry, I was late to the chat reome. Do you mean to just remove the code.jquery include code?